# React Native realtime get data

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Im trying to build a real time feed with react native and I have limited request to the api given.

How should I get the data realtime with using a lot of requests.

I used to do that:

```
setInterval(() => {this.getfeed()},1000);
```

Thanks

Comment: If you API supports it, you may want to look into [websockets].(https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#websocket-support).

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the API gives you information about the rate limits in its responses headers (e.g. `X-RateLimit-Limit`, `X-RateLimit-Remaining`). With this in mind, you can optimize your polling timing. Otherwise you need to figure the API limits yourself and poll accordingly.